# using localStorage to store numbers

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm writing a small game in Javascript. So far everything works perfectly, except I have no idea how localStorage works. I've looked everywhere for a decent explanation but everything is going way over my head.

I have an object and a number of variables that I want to store, all numbers.

```
land = {
total:150000000,
owned:1,
cost: 110,
housing: 14
};
```

As well as these variables,

```
var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var hours = 0;
var days = 0;
var years = 0;
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to save and load these objects/variables from localStorage?! Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage simply provides a way to store key value pairs. For example you can write something like `localStorage.myName = 'Ali'`
And layer when you call

```
localStorage.myName
```

You'll get 'Ali'

You can also store your object as is by saying

```
localStorage.land = land
```

But in this case your object will be stored as a string, so to retrieve it you can write something like

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.land)
```

Now myObj contains your land object.

And also note to store objects as strings you have to use JSON.stringify(yourObject)